# Is there any way/ function to unclick in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am basically selecting a checkbox by click function. And i want to unclick /unselect it.

$("#element").click();

Is there any function unclick() exists ?

I tried with with prop(),unbind(),off() but no luck. Please assist me in getting this right.

Comment: You can set `checked` to `false` and it will unchecked.

Comment: Already tried. It is also unchecking the checkbox but not triggering any onclick event. Since i have some custom code to be executed on click event, i want something like check() or uncheck().